# How to terminate (SIGINT) a subprocess in Haskell?

Tags: unix, haskell, process

I'm writing a small program in Haskell which manipulates the commands `arecordmidi` and `aplaymidi` to record short improvisations on my digital piano through MIDI. I will press the <kbd>R</kbd> key, my program will create a new subprocess with the command `arecordmidi`. When I press <kbd>R</kbd> again, I want my recording to stop, by terminating the command `arecordmidi`.

How do I terminate the `arecordmidi` subprocess? If in a shell, <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> would stop recording. This is what I want.

I'm using the following code to create the subprocess:

```
import System.Process

main = do
  let rec_command = "arecordmidi -p \"CASIO USB-MIDI\" myRecording.midi"
  process <- createProcess (shell rec_command)

  -- I could try the following code, but the documentation of System.Process 
  -- says it's bad to use terminateProcess:
  let (_, _, _, processHandle) = process
  terminateProcess processHandle
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`terminateProcess` sends a `SIGTERM` (terminate) signal to the process, which corresponds to the default behavior of the unix command `kill`, which generally is not what you want when trying to end a process nicely.

`Ctrl+C` sends the signal `SIGINT` (interrupt), which many applications handle by an orderly shutdown, and in your case probably results in the `arecordmidi` process saving outstanding data, and closing any pipes and files.

Looks like the way to send `SIGINT` with `System.Process` is with [`interruptProcessGroupOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process/docs/System-Process.html#v:interruptProcessGroupOf).

Comment: I was thinking about that too... Eventually resolved to use `terminateProcess` for now, since my small program is still only a draft.